# Gitlab is not showing commits after pushing

Tags: git, gitlab

After pushing i cannot see the commit in GitLab. It is still showing the page that a freshly created repo would have. I already tried the [Trouble Shooting Guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide), but the error is still there.

My vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName git.example.net
        DocumentRoot /home/git/gitlab/public/
        <Directory /home/git/gitlab/public/>
                AllowOverride all
                Options -MultiViews
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

rake gitlab:check RAILS_ shows the following:

```
    ENV=production
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.0 ? ... OK (1.7.1)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
update hook up-to-date? ... yes
update hooks in repos are links: ...
somerepo ... repository is empty

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... yes
Projects have satellites? ...
somerepo ... can't create, repository is empty
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.7.10)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

Listing of the /home/git directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 16 git  git  4096 Sep 17 20:45 gitlab
drwxr-xr-x  2 git  git  4096 Sep 17 20:09 gitlab-satellites
drwxr-xr-x  8 git  git  4096 Sep 17 21:40 gitlab-shell
drwxrws---  5 git  git  4096 Sep 17 21:37 repositories
```

Comment: What does `git branch -avvv` returns? Are you in a detached head state (in the git repo on the client side)?

Comment: I alredy tryed to push a fresh, new repo (same error) so I don't think that it is a problem with the git repo on itself.

git branch -avvv returns:

* master 5ec66e4 Bug fixes

Comment: Pusing a fresh new repo wouldn't work: you need at least one commit. What does `git remote -v` returns?

Comment: on my server it returns nothing. On my pc in the repo the following:

$ git remote -v
origin  git@git.example.net:path/to.git (fetch)
origin  git@git.example.net:path/to.git (push)

Comment: Is it GitLab 6.1? If yes, it seems that there is currently a bug. See in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/5101

Comment: Thank you. Thats the solution of my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Just close the merge request and reopen it. That will show up the missing commits. May be it is a bug in it.